# Finding the max in an array of Data-Structures

Tags: c++, data-structures, max

I have a text file of cars:

```
2014 Toyota Tacoma 115.12 1
2012 Honda CRV 85.10 0
2015 Ford Fusion 90.89 0
2013 GMC Yukon 110.43 0
2009 Dodge Neon 45.25 1
2011 Toyota Rav4 65.02 1
2012 Mazda CX5 86.75 1
2016 Subaru Outback 71.27 0
2015 Ford F150 190.83 1
2010 Toyota Corolla 50.36 1
```

I am trying to find the max which is the float but I am having trouble finding it as well as finding the rental cost of the cars. I have this so far but am still having trouble.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct car
{
    int year;
    char make[10];
    char model[10];     
    float price;
    int available;

} ;

void menu();

 // Main Function
int main ()
{
    // declare variables
    int carAmount = 10;
    int choice;
    car carLib[carAmount];
    char filename[10];
    ifstream carInData;
    float mostExpensive = 0;
    int MostExpensiveIndex;
    int count = 0;
    int days;
    int rentalCost = 0;

    //prompt user for input file
    cout << " Enter file name: ";
    cin >> filename;

    menu();

    carInData.open(filename);

    cin >> choice;

    if(carInData.is_open());
    {
        // read list of names into array
        for(cout; count < carAmount; count++){     

            carInData >> carLib[count].year >> carLib[count].make >> carLib[count].model >> carLib[count].price >> carLib[count].available;
            switch (choice){

                case 1:
                    if(carLib[count].available == 1)
                        cout << " Available ";
                    else
                        cout << " Unavailable ";


                    cout << carLib[count].year << " " << carLib[count].make << " " << carLib[count].model << " " << carLib[count].price << "  " << "\n";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    cout << " Enter car number and how many days " << "\n";
                    cout << " Days: ";
                    cin >> days;
                    cout << "\n" << "Car: ";
                    cin >> carLib[count].price;
                    rentalCost += days * count;
                    cout << " Rental Cost for " << days << " days is " << rentalCost;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    MostExpensiveIndex = count;
                    for(size_t carIndex = 0; carIndex < count; ++carIndex){
                        if(carLib[carAmount].price <= mostExpensive) continue;
                        mostExpensive = carLib[carIndex].price;
                        MostExpensiveIndex = carIndex;
                    }   
                    const car & carI = carLib[MostExpensiveIndex];

                    cout << " Most Expensive car is: " << MostExpensiveIndex << " " << carI.year << " " << carI.make << " " <<  carI.model << " "  << carI.price << "\n";

                    break;
            } 
        }
    }  

    return 0;
}


void menu(){
    cout << " 1 - Show Cars\n";
    cout << " 2 - Rental Cost\n";
    cout << " 3 - Most Expensive Car\n";
}
```

My output is displaying all my cars instead of the maximum one. This is the screenshot of the output

[image: output]

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: @user3286661 My output is displaying all my cars instead of the maximum one.

http://imgur.com/a/RJhZJ

Comment: @user3286661

I see my brackets were the issue affecting the maximum, but now my cars wont display when the user presses 1, it displays long numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
if(carLib[carAmount].price <= mostExpensive) continue;
```

with

```
if(carLib[carIndex].price <= mostExpensive) continue;
```

Correct code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct car {
    int year;
    char make[10];
    char model[10];
    float price;
    int available;

} ;

void menu();

// Main Function
int main ()
{
// declare variables
    int carAmount = 10;
    int choice;
    car carLib[carAmount];
    char filename[10];
    ifstream carInData;
    float mostExpensive = 0;
    int MostExpensiveIndex;
    int count = 0;
    int days;
    float rentalCost = 0;

    //prompt user for input file
    cout << " Enter file name: ";
    cin >> filename;

    menu();

    carInData.open(filename);

    cin >> choice;

    if (carInData.is_open()) {
        // read list of names into array


        for (; count < carAmount; count++) {

            carInData >> carLib[count].year >> carLib[count].make >> carLib[count].model >> carLib[count].price >> carLib[count].available;

        }
    }

    switch (choice) {

    case 1:
      for (int carIndex = 0; carIndex < carAmount; ++carIndex){
        if (carLib[carIndex].available == 1)
            cout << " Available ";
        else
            cout << " Unavailable ";


        cout << carLib[carIndex].year << " " << carLib[carIndex].make << " " << carLib[carIndex].model << " " << carLib[carIndex].price << "  " << "\n";
      }
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << " Enter car number and how many days " << "\n";
        cin >> count;
        cout << " Days: ";
        cin >> days;
        cout << "\n" << "Car: ";

        rentalCost = days * carLib[count].price;
        cout << " Rental Cost for " << days << " days is " << rentalCost << endl;
        break;

    case 3:


        MostExpensiveIndex = 0;
        for (size_t carIndex = 0; carIndex < carAmount; ++carIndex) {
            if (carLib[carIndex].price <= mostExpensive) continue;
            mostExpensive = carLib[carIndex].price;
            MostExpensiveIndex = carIndex;
        }
        const car & carI = carLib[MostExpensiveIndex];

        cout << " Most Expensive car is: " << MostExpensiveIndex << " " << carI.year << " " << carI.make << " " <<  carI.model << " "  << carI.price << "\n";

        break;

    }
    return 0;
}


void menu()
{
    cout << " 1 - Show Cars\n";
    cout << " 2 - Rental Cost\n";
    cout << " 3 - Most Expensive Car\n";
}
```

Comment: I did that, but for some reason it displays the car from the top of the list and that maximum as well.

Comment: I see my brackets were the issue affecting the maximum, but now my cars wont display when the user presses 1, it displays long numbers.

@user3286661